# How does the generalized effective action in Wetterich's exact RG scheme relate to observables at different scales?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory, 1pi-effective-action

I am not familiar with Wetterich's exact RG paradigm, and cannot understand the main idea behind it. I understand that if one could have solved the model and obtained the all the n-point functions then there would not have been any need for any RG analysis.

The Wilson-Polchinski RG framework [(see, for example, arxiv-0702365)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0702365.pdf) extends the ordinary purturbative RG approach beyond perturbative regimes. But it stills adheres to the same general principle: lowering the UV cutoff of the model and tracking the growth of various terms.

In Wettrich's approach [(See, for example, arxiv-0005122)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0005122.pdf), a generalized effective action, $\Gamma_k[\phi]$ is used, which is the 1PI generating functional with all modes below a momentum scale $k$ frozen (i.e., an IR cutoff at the momentum scale $k$).

Why is $\Gamma_{k}[\phi]$ useful for extracting information about IR physics? (To be more concrete, in Eq. 2.11 on page 17 of arxiv-0005122, it seems one gets back the same source, $J$, and not some coarse-grained version.)

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.